# In SPAGOBI how can i print date parameters in actuall report

Tags: mysql, spagobi

```
SELECT 
  b1.voucher_no,    
  b1.sl_name,   
  b2.sub_ledger_name,    
  b2.transaction_description,
  b2.gl_name  

  FROM

  a_bank_receipt_voucher b1  inner join a_bank_receipt_account_details b2 on b1.bank_receipt_id = b2.bank_receipt_id  

  WHERE

  b1.voucher_no = ?  AND b1.ac_date BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-06 ' 


  order by b1.voucher_no ASC limit 100
```

and my question here is how can i print date parameters (2013-06-01 and 2013-06-06)  in actuall report

( ex: i consider the 2013-06-01 as the from and 2013-06-06 as the to date)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution : When passing Date parameter .

1.pls select the data type = "DATE"  and also check the LOV file , whether data type is of 'DATE'.
2.check the date format you pass to the server  ex: dd-mm-yyyy, format in spagoBI  server may be different !!  you can edit date format  in SpagoBI server in the below path

All-In-One-SpagoBI/webapps/SpagoBI/WEB-INF/conf/config/data_access.xml

once completed , save the xml file and restart the server  and now check it